# Reports on completeness of User Profile information

Tags: user-profile

I have an on-premise install of SharePoint 2013. We use user-profile synchronization to get titles, departments and phone extensions, but leave it up to our staff to enter their About Me, Skills, and to add a photo if they wish.

Does anyone have a suggestion how I might be able to get reports on User Profile completeness - for instance:

1. list of all users that have filled out the About Me section
2. list of all users that have a photo
3. List of all users that have a photo AND About Me AND Skills

I am trying to put together a campaign to encourage usage of the Profiles and wonder how I'll measure it.

Many thanks for all ideas.

Comment: Something like Hyperfish might be useful, https://hyperfish.com

Comment: Nice suggestion on Hyperfish Eric, however the fields I'm looking to report on are in the SharePoint User Profile - not in AD.

Comment: I thought it could look into SP too, I haven't tried the product, just something new that's come out recently

Answer (score 0):

You could create console app to iterate and build csv file of fields you need.

```
using Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles;

// Code Block for Profile Loop
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(spURL))
{
    try
    {
        // Get our context and the profile manager object
        ServerContext context = ServerContext.GetContext(site);
        UserProfileManager profileManager = new UserProfileManager(context);

        // Define our holder strings
        string firstName = string.Empty, lastName = string.Empty;
        string department = string.Empty, customProperty = string.Empty;

        // Loop through each user in the profile manager
        foreach (UserProfile user in profileManager)
        {
            // grab the first and last name
            firstName = user[PropertyConstants.FirstName].Count > 0 ? user[PropertyConstants.FirstName].ToString() : string.Empty;
            lastName = user[PropertyConstants.LastName].Count > 0 ? user[PropertyConstants.LastName].ToString() : string.Empty;

            // grab the department
            department = user[PropertyConstants.Department].Count > 0 ? user[PropertyConstants.Department].ToString() : string.Empty;

            // grab a custom property
            customProperty = user["Custom Property Name"].Count > 0 ? user["Custom Property Name"].ToString() : string.Empty;
         }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        HandleException(ex);
    }
}
```

REF:http://blog.subtledetour.com/2010/02/04/loop-through-sharepoint-profiles/